# How to upgrade from Debian 8 Jessie to Debian 9 Stretch?

Tags: debian, apt, upgrade, dist-upgrade

I've tried to run command `apt-get update && apt-get upgrade && apt-get dist-upgrade` as root, but nothing happens. I think that the problem is in non-fully complete apt sources. Am I right? What sources I need to set?

Comment: From the debian web site “The next release of Debian is codenamed "stretch" — no release date has been set”. You can still install it, but I do not recommend it (unless you have a good reason, know what you are doing, and do it on a 2nd computer). The procedure will be more complex that the standard one, that you showed above.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Update your apt repositories to use stretch instead of jessie (This can be done manually with a text editor, but sed can be used to automatically update the file.)

```
[user@debian-9 ~]$ sudo sed -i 's/jessie/stretch/g' /etc/apt/sources.list
```

**Please note** : Debian 9 (Stretch) is marked testing for a reason. You may notice stability problems when using it.

Comment: Yes, when stretch becomes *stable*, then the procedure in the question will work. **You are not meant to be using it yet.**

Comment: I advise using our search field, and searching for stretch to have a feeling of what can go wrong.

Answer (score 1):

The following post provides the exact steps that one need to take in order to upgrade Debian 8 Jessie to Debian 9 Stretch:

https://economictheoryblog.com/2018/08/23/upgrade-debian-8-to-9/

Answer (score -2):

```
echo 'deb http://httpredir.debian.org/debian/ stretch main contrib non-free
deb-src http://httpredir.debian.org/debian/ stretch main contrib non-free

deb http://httpredir.debian.org/debian/ stretch-updates main contrib non-free
deb-src http://httpredir.debian.org/debian/ stretch-updates main contrib non-free

deb http://httpredir.debian.org/debian/ stretch-proposed-updates main contrib non-free
deb-src http://httpredir.debian.org/debian/ stretch-proposed-updates main contrib non-free

deb http://security.debian.org/ stretch/updates main contrib non-free
deb-src http://security.debian.org/ stretch/updates main contrib non-free' > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/stretch.list
```

Comment: Context please.

Comment: Don't do it. When stretch becomes stable, then the procedure in the question will work. You are not meant to be using it yet.

Comment: The above will only work if logged in as root, don't do it. Instead use something like `sudo tee`. I won't give the full solution, as I don't want to be responsible for what happens if you upgrade, unless I get informed consent.

Comment: The httpredir.debian.org is obsolete and have been redirected to deb.debian.org. According to deb.debian.org only **apt in stretch and later** is able to make use of this.